# Does a piecewise-continuous function need to be defined at its points of discontinuities?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, fourier-series, laplace-transform

Is the following function considered piecewise-continuous??

I'm reading conflcting definitions in different places: some highlight that that the function need not be defined at the (jump/removable) discontinuities, others explicitly state that the end-points of the pieces must be well-defined. Hmm!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be confusing a "piecewise-continuous function" with a continuous "piecewise function" (that is, a function defined piecewise).  Piecewise functions must be defined on the endpoints of their subdomains if they are to be continuous on a larger interval, but piecewise-continuous functions need only approach finite limits as they approach the endpoints of their subdomains.  Both the Wikipedia article and the lecture notes seem to be in agreement on this, though the Wikipedia article spends more time on when a piecewise-defined function is continuous than on when a function is piecewise-continuous.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. The wikipedia citation was a bad example. My course notes states this: "A function is said to be **piecewise continuous** if its graph consists of a finite number of continuous pieces on any part of its domain. The endpoints of the pieces must be well-defined." Several other places also explain it like this. So, I'm still undecided.

Comment: I see.  Perhaps "the endpoints of the pieces must be well-defined" is indicating that the one-sided limits have to exist for the function to be piecewise continuous?  But if that's not how it's used in your notes I would chalk it up to a genuine disagreement; functions like the one in the picture are generally considered piecewise continuous.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for your input; I'll go with your definition. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The given piecewise function is indeed **piecewise-continuous** (since each piece is continuous). This remains true should we add a new piece—well, point—at $x_0.$ That is, its piecewise continuity is not affected by whether it is defined at $x_0.$

(The given piecewise function is also **continuous**, like how the function $\frac1x,$ with domain $\mathbb R{\setminus}\{0\},$ is continuous. Of course, continuity is lost once we add a new piece—well, point—at $x_0.)$